# Using an ANTLR Lexer For Syntax Coloring: Module excluded from the target platform error

Tags: netbeans, antlr, syntax-highlighting, antlr4, netbeans-platform

I'm new to Netbeans Platform Development and following [this tutorial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SyntaxColoringANTLR).

When I try to build the project I get this error:

`Module org.netbeans.modules.editor.util excluded from the target platform`
There are apparently no errors in the app.

I'm using

- NB 8.0
- JDK jdk1.7.0_45
- OS Win 8.1

What might be going wrong?

**UPDATE**:
Somehow the module was excluded via the `disabled.modules` in the  `platform.properties` properties file.

When i comment it out (or remove it), it runs but gives this warning

[image]

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I nailed part of the problem. The error occurred because of unresolved dependencies.

I went through the tut again on a Linux Mint with NB7.4.
Now I get no errors but facing yet another problem. Now as I open a file, it opens the file but the Cookie Editor disappears.

I'm expecting someone will help on the second Issue.

[image]

*Moderators: I'm not sure how will you guys respond to this but I've no clue how to go about my half solved problem.*